# How to extract text from a hyphen separated list with the possibility of new lines (thus multiple entries) within a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column that contains football fixtures with the home and away teams being separated by a hyphen. There may be multiple fixtures within a cell, and these would be done by a new line within the cell.

What I want to do is separate the home and away teams into new cells. I could do the home team with:

```
=LEFT(B2, SEARCH("-",B2,1)-1)
```

But this doesn't take into account new lines within the cell.

How could I grab the home and away teams from a cell (including entries that are a on a new line)?

demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GVnW6JQLNUuZaEDU9uRq2JezCM8-myKT064OlJk9kPU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some AppsScript code to help you!

[Create a new AppsScript file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and paste this code:

```
function splitTeams(cellData) {
  return cellData.split('-');
}
function hasOddIndex(item, index) {
  return index%2==0;
}
function hasEvenIndex(item, index) {
  return index%2!=0;
}

function getHomeTeams(cellData) {
  var homeTeams = [];
  homeTeams = splitTeams(cellData).filter(hasOddIndex);
  return homeTeams.join('\n');
}
function getAwayTeams(cellData) {
  var awayTeams = [];
  awayTeams = splitTeams(cellData).filter(hasEvenIndex);
  return awayTeams.join('\n');
}
```

Now you can use on your spreadsheet the functions `=getHomeTeams()` and `=getAwayTeam()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

sample formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(
TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(A2:A&char(10),A2:A<>""),,2^99),char(10))),"-")))`

result:

```
Sevilla     Sociedad
Leicester   Newcastle
Napoli      Brescia
Leicester   Newcastle
Leicester   Newcastle
Napoli      Brescia
```

each team in a separate cell

---

sample formula #2:

`=FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,REPT("([^-\n]*) [-v]s? ([^-\n]*)\n?",1+LEN(A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,char(10),)))),A2:A<>"")`

result:

```
Sevilla     Sociedad                
Leicester   Newcastle               
Napoli      Brescia     Leicester   Newcastle       
Leicester   Newcastle   Napoli      Brescia Espanyol    Valladolid
Napoli      Brescia     Leicester   Newcastle
```

teams in corresponding lines

---

sample formula #3

`=FILTER(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,
  REPT("([^-\n]*) [-v]s? ([^-\n]*)\n?",1+LEN(A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,char(10),))),
  VLOOKUP(1+LEN(A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,char(10),)),E2:F4,2,)),"-"),A2:A<>"")`

[image]
The formula uses the helper table:

```
1    $1-$2
2    $1
     $3-$2
     $4"
3    $1
     $3
     $5-$2
     $4
     $6
```

This helper table is a regular expression replacement: `$1, $2, $3...` are team numbers to return.

Comment: Sweet. How could I set the home team names that are in the same cell, to then render in the same cell again? i.e. 4th column, keep Napoli and Leicster in the same cell.

Comment: Yes, possible, please see the edit. The regex replacement is a tricky part, I've made a helper table in order to simplify the final formula.